# How do bootstrap breakpoints tell the difference between a mobile device and full size monitor with the same resolution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

According to the documentation, the breakpoints are based almost exclusively on the pixel width of the viewport, with the exact values being:

- 0+ = xs
- 576+ = sm
- 768+ = md
- 992+ = lg
- 1200+ = xl

The only thing though is that just about every phone nowadays has a resolution of at least 1080p. How come a phone with a width of 1080 pixels still displays layouts using the sm or xs breakpoint rules instead of the correct lg display rules? How do these breakpoints really work that they can tell the difference between my 1080x1920 phone screen and my 1080x1920 vertical monitor?

Answer (score 0):

It is working because of the use of a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Which is also mentioned and explained in their [introduction page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag).